# Simple javascript function return an undefined string

Tags: javascript, html

I'm actually trying to build a multilingual website using javascript.

Sound simple but i'm stuck with the function who always return undefined for a reason I don't get.

When I debug it on Chrome lang is correctly initialized with "fr" if I click on the french button.
But when it has to read the value lang.welcome I always see "undefined".

```css
    <script>
        function changeLanguage(language) {

            var en = {
                welcome: "Welcome!"
            }

            var fr = {
                welcome: "Salut!"
            }

            if (language === "fr") {
                lang = "fr"
            }
            else {
                lang = "en"
            }

            // set translation
            document.getElementById("welcome").innerHTML = lang.welcome;
        }
    </script>
```

```html
        <input type="button" value="fr" onclick="changeLanguage(this.value)">
        <input type="button" value="en" onclick="changeLanguage(this.value)">

        <p id="welcome">Welcome</p>
```

Comment: It should be `lang = fr` and `lang = en` so that `lang` references the variable you've defined previously. By doing `lang = "fr"` and `lang = "en"`, you're just setting it to a string, and then trying to do `"fr".welcome` / `"en".welcome`, which isn't valid.

Comment: @TylerRoper Thanks, it works. You can post it as an answer :-)

Comment: It seems more like a typo or a duplicate, so I think in all honesty it would be better off just being deleted to reduce clutter :)

Comment: I can't since someone answered the question :p But thanks :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are setting lang as a string.

```
        if (language === "fr") {
            lang = "fr"
        }
        else {
            lang = "en"
        }
```

So when you try to access "fr".welcome it correctly states undefined.

Instead set it

```
        if (language === "fr") {
            lang = fr;
        }
        else {
            lang = en;
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
 function changeLanguage() {
 
            var en = {
                welcome: "Welcome!"
            }

            var fr = {
                welcome: "Salut!"
            }

            if (event.target.value === "fr") {
                lang = fr;
            }
            else {
                lang = en;
            }

            // set translation
            document.getElementById("welcome").innerHTML = lang.welcome;
        }
```

```css
<script>
       
    </script>
```

```html
<input type="button" value="fr" onclick="changeLanguage()">
        <input type="button" value="en" onclick="changeLanguage()">

        <p id="welcome">Welcome!!</p>
```